# Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/Consts with httpcomponents dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dex

I am using below imports for my uploader (a module in my project not in app module) :

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
```

> httpcore:4.4.2 httpmime:4.5

contains this imports. when i want to compile the code i got below error in my Gradle console.

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/Consts;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

this is my build.gradle of this module :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion as Integer
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion as String

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion as Integer
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion as Integer
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode as Integer
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName as String
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':lib-ComponentsUtils')

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.2'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
}
```

Note : i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917172/multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-apache-http-consts-with-http-client-dependency) question and i am using

```
exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
```

Comment: do you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this http library and use retrofit lib. retrofit is fast and short than httpclient library.

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1
```

Refer this

https://square.github.io/retrofit/